# What is launching all of these rpc.statd processes?

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs, rpc

On of our servers -- running CentOS 6 x86_64 -- we're seeing a lot unusual activity with `rpc.statd`.  We have `rpc.statd` configured to run on a static port via `/etc/sysconfig/nfs`:

```
MOUNTD_PORT=892
STATD_PORT=662
QUOTAD_PORT=875
```

And this does result in `rpc.statd` running and listening on this port as expected:

```
# ps -fe | grep rpc.statd | grep 662
rpcuser  23129     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd -p 662
```

What's odd is that on this system, there are also numerous other `rpc.statd` instances running with the `--no-notify` flag:

```
rpcuser    808     1  0 02:23 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser   2052     1  0 07:17 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser   3558     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser   5787     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser   6499     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser   8834     1  0 03:21 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser   9661     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  13702     1  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  14813     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  15375     1  0 08:39 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  15376     1  0 04:26 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  19782     1  0 09:36 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  20491     1  0 05:36 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  23136     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  23320     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  26145     1  0 10:10 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  26480     1  0 06:24 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  26598     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  26821     1  0 01:15 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
rpcuser  28255     1  0 Apr30 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd --no-notify
```

Also odd is that one of these processes has apparently usurped the
original `rpc.statd` process as far as rpcbind is concerned.  Running
`rpcinfo` reports statd on the following ports:

```
# rpcinfo -p
...
100024    1   udp  34322  status
100024    1   tcp  41686  status
```

These correspond to PID 26145 (which you can see is one of the
`rpc.statd` instances in the above output from `ps`).

This wouldn't be a problem if everything is working, but yesterday the
system began to experience a problem with NFS mounts...any attempt to
mount a new filesystem would result in:

```
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

Killing off all the `rpc.statd` services "resolved" the problem, but
we're puzzled as to what's going on here.  We've never seen this
behavior on our similarly configured CentOS 5 systems.

Comment: Since rpc.statd is started by mount.nfs, this could be a result of many mount attempts after nfs hickups. Anything in the logs with a matching STIME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this appears to be partly our fault and partly a bug in RedHat's `authconfig` command.  Our Puppet configuration was causing `authconfig --updateall` to be run every hour.  This was unnecessary but generally it shouldn't be a problem...except that `authconfig` restarts the `rpcbind` service.

Restart `rpcbind` causes it to forget about all the services that have registered with it.  While `authconfig` will then restart NIS-related services, this results in a situation where `rpc.statd` is still running but no longer registered with `rpcbind` -- which makes it effectively invisible from the point of view of applications that attempt to find it via `rpcbind`.

I've fixed our Puppet configuration so that it is no longer calling `authconfig` like this, and I've opened bug [818246](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=818246) with RedHat.

Comment: ...which RedHat has, of course, ignored.  C'est la vie.